# What are the current numbers for freight/goods/workers per zone in Simcity 2013

Tags: simcity-2013

I've been trying to find some good numbers for zone statistics, and due to various patches, there has been a great deal of disparity between the results I've found. The page at http://forum.ea.com/eaforum/posts/list/9365293.page has fantastic information, but due to the date of the post I'm sure it is quite inaccurate at this point. Does anyone know where to find up to date data like this? I would gladly do some testing myself to generate a new list, but I won't have access to the game until I get home in a couple of days, and I'd like to crunch some numbers and do some planning beforehand.

Comment: @AmyB - Sure, except for the fact that that answer is just as old as the link I provided. The game changed quite drastically from what I understand.

Comment: The game hasn't changed at all.  They never did a balance patch, only bugfixes, DLC and CoT expansion.  Look, you sound new to the game so I want to link the best thing I ever wrote on it here: https://www.reddit.com/r/SimCity/comments/1vt1ba/how_does_population_work_i_need_help_simcity_2013/cevlg7e

Comment: @AmyB - Ah, okay. I read somewhere that they intended to make changes to place more importance on industrial zones that would have changed these numbers. I guess that never happened? I'd so, toss an answer up and I'll mark this answered to your credit. Thank you, sir.

Comment: The tuning that was done was all happiness based.  Here's the list of updates http://forum.ea.com/eaforum/forums/show/4182.page .  In Update 2.0, residential happiness was tuned to prevent R-only cities.  In Update 4.0, residential happiness was again tuned to make C more important.  In Update 6.0, commercial happiness was tuned to make I more important - however, RC cities (no I) are still possible (the challenge being finding jobs) and RI cities (no C) are still possible and easy (with maybe 1 C building to give crime a target).  I only is also possible if you can get commuters from region.